# Install linux on Motorola L6 Phone

Tags: linux

I have a Motorola L6 cell phone that I'm no longer using, including pc connector cable, and just for the fun of it I was wondering if it were possible to install linux on the phone.  Not to make any calls — I don't have service for it — just to see if I could get it working and what apps it might be able to use.

I don't really expect to find anything useful, but I thought it might be worth asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check http://forum.motofan.ru/index.php?showtopic=117307 (in Russian), but a generic distro will never support these phones, because they need custom loader, custom kernel and a lot of not yet written drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Not trivially, i think - most phones have fairly locked down hardware, and reflashing the OS might require a mix of hardware and software hacking. You're going to also need to work out what processor the phone uses, and if there's a port for it, and how to get the OS in there.

Its one of those 'if you need to ask, its probably going to be really hard to do' things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a linux distro would fit into a cell phone,and even if it did,i don't think the phone would have the capabilities of actually running the system

Comment: You'd be surprised.  An awful lot of cell phones are already running linux.  It's just a matter of what you put on top of the kernel.

Comment: they might be running linux,but not the distros we use,they customize the kernel specifically for the phone itself

but good luck anyways ;)